# Database design for Splitwise

Tags: database-design

I am Trying to do DDD for splitwise. Use cases are

1. ability to add, remove, edit transaction with
2. we should be able to create a group as well as one-one expenditures.
3. We should be able to show simplified balance so that number of money exchanges are minimised.

Here is what i have come so far[image]
**User**: Individual User

**TransactionGroup**: Group against which transaction can be added (1-1 transactions are also modelled as group with only 2 participants.)

**GroupMemebers**: Mapping of users in a group.

**Transaction**: Record of expenditure. example 1: User1 paid 200 split equally among User1, User2. example 2: User1 paid 100, User2 paid 200 split in 40:60. While adding a transaction I will create ledger entries as well.

**Ledger**: Every transaction is broken into multiple ledger entries telling the effective money lending has happened in a transaction. This table is mainly to calculate Group Account balance. instead of iterating through all the Transactions, I can just use sql queries on ledger table.

**Question 1: But I am unsure of how to model simplified view**.

**Option A**: First add transaction, ledger entries then calculate simplified view using ledger entries? This will make simplified view eventually consistent.

**Option B**: Get existing ledger entries merge it with new transaction and update TransactionGroup, Transaction, Ledger by a lock on TransactionGroup.

**Question 2: How to model data archival?**

If one group has been active for a very long time. It will accumulate lots of entries and calculating balance using ledger will take a long time. So we just want to carry roll over from transactions older than 1 year. I am planning to get all transaction older than one year. calculate simplifiedView, persist as a transaction. But i am not sure how to model for deletion of older transaction. In the same transaction. Are there better ways to do rollover than What I am thinking of?